# how can I check if a doc in firebase exist?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to check if a document in my firebase console exist but I cannot use doc and dont know why . Maybe anyone can help heres my code

```
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getalldata();
    

  }

  getalldata() async {
    //get videos as future
    myVideos = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userid)
        .get();
        
    var documents = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userid)
        .get();
    
    for (var item in documents.docs) {
      likes = item.data()['likes'].length + likes;
    }
 
    setState(() {
      dataisthere = true;
    });
  }
```

So in the documents var I wanna check if documents exists.
And them I wanna use the value inside an if else check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getalldata();
    

  }

  getalldata() async {
    //get videos as future
    myVideos = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userid)
        .get();
        
    var documents = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: widget.userid)
        .get();
    if(documents.docs.isNotEmpty){
    for (var item in documents.docs) {
      likes = item.data()['likes'].length + likes;
    }
     setState(() {
      dataisthere = true;
    });
   } else{
  setState(() {
      dataisthere = false;
    });
    }
   }
```

Comment: I got it thanks man a lot ! You always saving me haha. GG

Comment: You you think the future builder will be a problem for me .Im asking that because if user like post something will it be updated or not ? So should I change it to a streambuilder or not ?

Comment: Anytime mate! Glad to help, keep up the great work, your progress is noticeable everyday! Just be sure you are grasping what the answers on SO mean, not just getting the code to work. Explanations should be included in the answer ideally, but always ask to clear anything up, especially if I was answering, don't hesitate.

Comment: Regarding your question, I'd suggest stream builder, it'll give a better look and feel for your application, and users don't have to refresh to see the new data. Regarding billing, it's the same thing, you are only charged per document change, so either ways it's the same amount of reads, but the experience is far better. Seeing it update live is always cooler.

Comment: Ok you need to help me convert that into a streambuilder. Can You ?

Comment: Of course, write in a separate post, get working on it, and I'll gladly assist if I'm available when you post it. You have to write yourself first. But it's not hard, instead of future, you change the word to stream, and instead of `get`, you change it to `snapshot`. The documentation is amazing, [read it here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes).

Comment: Ok but how do I do this with the for loop and the if check ?

Comment: maybe you can also check my newest post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953105/why-im-getting-this-error-lifecyclestate-elementlifecycle-defunct-is-not